# How to create a vertical flexbox with one fixed-height top div, and one remaining-height middle div that can overflow?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a flexbox that occupies the whole height of my page. It has 2 divs inside: a top div with `height: 80px`, and a bottom div, which will occupy the remaining space. The problem is: that bottom div has content that can overflow. When this happens, **the height: 80px** of the top div is completely ignored and it shrinks. How do I guarantee that my top-div will not shrink based on the overflow of the bottom div?

[Here is the demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/80617u8k/3/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of flex wasn't quite valid.  Try this:   Fiddle  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sgvawqfp/)

CSS

```
* { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; }
#page {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#top {
  background-color: #999;
  flex: 0 1 80px; /* Change 80px if diff needed, it is the basis parameter.     It means that the base height will be 100px before growing or shrinking. */
}
#bottom {
  background-color: #d7d7d7;
  flex:4 0 400px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: What wasn't quite valid about my flex?

Comment: 1. You use flex-grow on the child elements inside the flex container.  2. Calling display: flex in the child elements does nothing for it unless it too has child elements inside it.  So when you called flex-direction and flex-wrap inside the child element, it did nothing because it was not the parent flex container.  For more reference check out this guide http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Hope that helps you understand better, can be a little confusing getting into flexbox.  In the link, examples are separated by parent(left) and child(right) attributes when using flexbox.